# Finding isometries

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, optimization, isometry

I was wondering if for a given set of points $x_1,...,x_n$, $n > 2$, and two metric spaces $(X,d_1),(Y,d_2)$,  $X \neq Y$, it s possible
to find a continuous mapping $T: X \rightarrow Y $, such that $d_1(x_i,x_j) = d_2(T(x_i),T(x_j))$ for all pairs of indices $(i,j)$. I'm sure there s something around in the optimisation literature but I cant seem to find any keywords; maybe some optimal transport related topic. Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you intend for $d_1(x_i,x_j)$ to be constant for all $x_i, x_j$?

Comment: thx, it was an error. already edited it

Comment: Is $T: X \to X$ where $X$ is the only set in play?  In other words, are $d_1$ and $d_2$ metrics on the same $X$?

Comment: What if there is only one pair of points, and $d_1(x,y)\not=d_2(x,y)$?

Comment: True, but I d assume more than one point

Comment: The *definition* of $T: X \to Y$ being an isometry is that $d_2(T(x), T(y))=d_1(x,y)$ for all $x, y \in X$.  Your problem is a bit redundant.

Comment: Now:  what does it mean for $T$ to be an isometry with finite domain?  The only finite metric spaces are discrete.

Comment: so what i want is basically a mapping T for which the isometric property holds for given finite points. And that map can be extended onto the whole X but is not anymore necessarily an isometry.

Comment: You should edit that into your question.  That is very different than what is currently asked.

Comment: thanks for the tip. i edited it

Comment: Here's what you need to say.  Given metric spaces $(X,d_1)$ and $(Y,d_2)$, you want to know about the existence of a continous map $T: X \to Y$ such that the conditions on the $x_i$'s are met.  Do not call $T$ an isometry, because it is not.

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't always possible. Here is an extreme counterexample.

Let $X$ be the real line but under the discrete metric $d_1$.  Let $Y$ be the real line under the ordinary metric $d_2$.  Take 3 distinct points $x_1, x_2$ and $x_3$ in $X$.  Suppose you could find a continuous map $T: X \to Y$ preserving the distances between all the $x_i$.

Since $X$ has the discrete metric this means that $d_2(T(x_i), T(x_j))=1$ whenever $i \neq j$.  Suppose, without loss of generality, that the $x_i$ are indexed so that $T(x_1) < T(x_2) < T(x_3)$.  This is clearly impossible since now $T(x_1)$ and $T(x_3)$ are now distance 2 apart.